# Add/Remove/Toggle Classes - good/bad practice?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm relatively new to the world of JavaScript, and have a question for you. I'm doing a simple JavaScript game, and I have several of these type of things to change, add, and remove classes when a button is clicked on. Now my question is, is this type of thing considered bad practice to have all of these listed like this? Is there a better way? Or is this totally fine?

```
$('#topsbtn').click(function () {
    $(".bluetops").toggleClass('hidetops');
    $(".bluetops").toggleClass('showtops');
    $(".greentops").removeClass('showtops');
    $(".greentops").addClass('hidetops');
    $(".purpletops").removeClass('showtops');
    $(".purpletops").addClass('hidetops');
    $(".redtops").removeClass('showtops');
    $(".redtops").addClass('hidetops');
    $(".pinktops").removeClass('showtops');
    $(".pinktops").addClass('hidetops');
    $(".yellowtops").removeClass('showtops');
    $(".yellowtops").addClass('hidetops');
});
```

EDIT: The top ones toggle the option, and the following are to make sure the other options are turned off when this button is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pretty sure `$(".greentops, .purpletops").removeClass("showtops")` will work for you

Comment: I don't know what yo are doing and why, but I don't think you have other option

Comment: I've added an edit as to why I have all of these. Hopefully adding some insight.

Comment: This is not a SO type of question

Comment: likewise `$(".bluetops").toggleClass("hidetops showtops")` should work. note the space separated classes, vs the comma separated selectors in `$()`

Comment: I'm sorry. I truly didn't realize asking if there was a better way to do something was considered a poor question.

Comment: Since you have functioning code that you wrote yourself, your question is probably on-topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but see their [on-topic help page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How toAsk](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to be sure.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even know this existed! I shall be sure to post there in the future.

Comment: You might be able to improve this, but it is hard to understand your options without being able to review the HTML and CSS associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in another answer you could abstract the functionality, but without knowing the structure of your game I can only suggest the following: add chaining `( thing.something().somethingElse().blah() )` and group selectors with commas `( '.greentops,.redtops' )` and jQuery will find them all.

```
$('#topsbtn').click(function () {
    $(".bluetops").toggleClass('hidetops');
    $(".bluetops").toggleClass('showtops');
    // this is a shortcut, you can add multiple classes in the selector and then chain the functions.
    $(".greentops,.purpletops,.redtops,.pinktops,.yellowtops").removeClass('showtops').addClass('showtops');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice principle at play here would be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Do not repeat yourself).

Your functionality *works*, but whenever you see multiples of methods/actions, it's a dead givewaway that you should probably extract out the functionality (aka [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_principle_(computer_programming))) to be more scalable.

Hope you continue to learn well.